# Matrix Algebraic Operations, If AA = AB, does A = B?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A and B are 2 x 2 matrices and A is not a zero matrix.  How is the following proof incorrect?

Since AA = AB, AA - AB = 0
A (A - B) = 0 and since A does not equal zero, then A - B = 0, therefore A = B.

Thank you

Comment: Because it is possible for a product of non-zero matrices to equal zero.

Comment: @user1551 $A$ is supposed to be different from $0$.

Comment: I see. I read the OP too quickly.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}_{=A}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}3 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}_{=B}$$
**EDIT** Here's an example where the product is not $0$.
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}}_{=A}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}}_{=B}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's not true in general, you need an aditional hypotesis, that $A$ is inversible. In this case your statement is true.

Comment: I wonder if it's enough to require just that $A$ is not a zero divisor. I don't know offhand whether or not these conditions are equivalent.